# Proving Conditional Cauchy Schwartz inequality.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, solution-verification

currently I try to solve the following exercise $8.2.6$ in Klenke Probability Theory for fun.
It states the following:

Let $X,Y \in L^2(P)$ be random variables on $(\Omega,F,P)$ then prove the conditional Cauchy-Schwartz inequality given by
$$
E[XY \mid F]^2 \leq E[X^2 \mid F] \times E[Y^2 \mid F].
$$

I am aware that a solution is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4203405/proof-of-cauchy-schwarz-inequality-for-conditional-expectations), although it is correct it seems that proof is odly not using the properties one learned during the chapter, which indicates that their might be a solution using the properties of conditional expectation plus the already known C.S. inequality. Thus here is my try:

Let us denote $Z=E[XY \mid F]$ (the existens is clear by chapter), then observe by Jensen's inequality one has
$$
Z^2 \leq E[X^2 Y^2 \mid F].
$$
Secondly observe that
$$
X^2+Y^2-X^2Y^2 \geq X^2 + Y^2 - 2 X^2 Y^2 = (X-Y)^2 \geq 0,
$$
which directly implies $X^2 Y^2 \leq X^2 + Y^2$. Since $E[U \mid F] \leq E[V \mid F]$ if $U \leq V$ almost surely, using the first inequality and linearity yields directly
$$
Z^2 \leq E[(XY)^2 \mid F] \leq E[X^2 \mid F] + E[Y^2 \mid F],
$$
which finishes the proof. Is this correct? (I am a bit surprised I didn't need original Cauchy Schwartz **explicitly**, probably still used in Jensen's). Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1:** I see that my inequality above is obviously wrong, but here is a way to fix things consider the case that $|X|,|Y| \leq 1$ then $X^2 \geq X^2 Y^2$, hence in this case
$$
X^2 + Y^2 - X^2 Y^2 \geq 2 X^2 Y^2 - X^2 Y^2 = X^2 Y^2 \geq 0,
$$
thus our desired inequality holds. But this case actually sufficies, since taking $\tilde{X} = \frac{X}{E[X]+E[Y]}, \tilde{Y} = \frac{Y}{E[X]+E[Y]}$ then gives
$$
E[\tilde{X} \tilde{Y} \mid F]^2 \leq E[\tilde{X}^2 \mid F] + E[\tilde{Y}^2 \mid F],
$$
which again gives the correct result.

Comment: Yeah you can repeat the proof of the ordinary Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to get the conditional one. If you want, you can alternatively deduce the conditional one from the usual one by using a conditional probability kernels, which turns a conditional expectation into an expectation against the kernel.

Comment: In the case of the kernel how do you deal with the case of the kernel how do you translate the kernel squared (after applying Cauchy Schwart) back into something that gives the Kernel of $E[X^2|F]$?

Comment: Use the kernel $\kappa_{\mathcal{F}, (X, Y)}$ for the conditional distribution of $(X, Y)$ given $\mathcal{F}$.